# Check if value in an array of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-class

I recently wrote a code that had all attributes stored separately in different arrays like

```
order_id = []
order_name = []
order_products = []
order_total = []
```

And when importing new orders through an API request I would check if I already have that order by doing

```
if new_order_id in order_id:
    # do new order stuff
```

Now I want to change the code so that order is a class that has id, name, products and total as attributes and all orders are stored in an array called orders. Is there an easy way to check if the new order id matches the id of any order objects in the orders array?

Comment: `if new_order_id in [order.id for order in orders]` would be a simple way. Better to use a dictionary mapping id -> object instead though.

Comment: Yes! Instead of `new_order_id` use `new_order.id` where `new_order` is an instance of your new class.

Comment: @rdas , thank you, I will look into both of those options.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I don't want to process the JSON data to turn the new order into a class if I don't have to. It's not actually a variable called `new_order_id`. It looks more like `order['order_number']`

Comment: You wrote "now I want to change the code so that order is a class" ‍♂️ Now it's unclear to me what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class oder():
    def __init__(self, id, name, products, total):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.products = products
        self.total = total
    
oders=[]# Class objects are here

if new.id in [oder.id for oder in oders]:
    #Place an Order
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to test for the existence of an object in a container is to give the object a "value" by way of the `__eq__` magic method. For example:

```
class Order:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.order_id = id
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.order_id == other

order_list = [Order('123'), Order('456')]
```

Then you can test for order numbers:

```
>>> '123' in order_list
True
>>> '345' in order_list
False
```